# Getting the index of an element of an JSON array in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having a JSON array of numbers like [16, 9, 11, 22, 23, 12]. I would like to get the index of numbers within the array. For example is I say that I would like to have the index of 9, it should return 1.

I tried using below mentioned query in MySQL, but getting null.

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(CAST('[16, 9, 11, 22, 23, 12]' AS JSON),'one',9)
```

Do you guys have solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

`CAST` is not necessary here. But array values should be quoted as

> `JSON_SEARCH(json_doc, one_or_all, search_str[, escape_char[, path] ...])`
>
> Returns the path to the given **string** within a JSON document.

```
SELECT json_search('["16", "9", "11", "22", "23", "12"]', 'one', '9');
```

returns `"$[1]"`